# How to upgrade the package in virtual environment only in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have created the virtual env. I am able to see the list of packages installed using the following command

```
pip freeze > my-awesome-env-req.txt
```

Now, I want to upgrade a particular package in virtual environment. I ran the following command after successfully activating my virtual env.

```
pip install upgrade sqlalchemy
```

The package is upgraded both in the global and virtual environment.

I want the package to be upgraded for virtual environment only.

Comment: What is the output of `command -v pip` before and after activating the virtualenv?

Comment: Specified command search directory bad
Too many paramters

Comment: What about 'which pip' before and after?

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute the pip command from within the Activated Virtual env..

Comment: I have executed the command from activated virtual env only but the package is upgraded both for the virtual and global environments.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that you're using the virtual environment's Python binary. For example, if you're in the root directory of the venv, you can run

```bash
./bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy
```

to upgrade the `sqlalchemy` package in the venv. Otherwise, running the `pip` or `python3.*` command could use the system-wide binary (depending on how your `$PATH` and shell aliases are set up).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the virtual environment with a new installation of Python and pip.
eg:

```
conda create -n myVirtualEnv python pip
source activate myVirtualEnv
pip install upgrade sqlalchemy
```

Ran into the same problem with seaborn...